# Using Cloudfront as reverse proxy across multiple VPC's

Tags: amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-vpc

I have 1 server 'A' that currently handles both static requests as well as requests made to the backend (ex. request path = /api*). However, the endpoint to this server 'A' is getting updated to server 'B' run by another team in a different vpc.

I would like to user CloudFront to route the backend requests originally made to server 'A' (/api*) to our backend server 'C'. Would this be possible to use Cloudfront across VPC's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. CloudFront exists completely outside of any of your VPCs and does not care if your origin servers are in a specific VPC or if they are even in AWS.

Comment: So i would use the default origin as the server IP for the new Server 'B'  that may or may not be using AWS, while creating a second origin pointing to server 'C's elb correct? And create the proper behaviors pointing to server 'C' for '/api*'?

Comment: Hey @Mark B
I know you answered this, but there was another issue that came up 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584582/forwarding-path-to-origin-in-cloudfront

i was wondering if i could borrow your brain again..